# The product of two function limits

Tags: limits, functions, axioms

I'm having problems understanding one of the rules of the algebra of functional limits, specifically this one:

$\lim_{x \to a}[f(x)\cdot g(x)]=\lim_{x \to a} f(x)\cdot \lim_{x \to a}g(x)$

I have a counter example in mind, which I know doesn't hold for some reason, just now sure why. If we let

$f(x)=x-a$ $,$ $g(x)=a$

then

$\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=0$ , $\lim_{x \to a}g(x)=a$ therefore $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)\cdot \lim_{x \to a}g(x)=0$

but

$\lim_{x \to a}[f(x)\cdot g(x)]=\lim_{x \to a}[a\cdot(a-x)]=\lim_{x \to a}[a^2-ax]=a$

Would love any insight into where I've gone wrong, thank you.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x \to a} a^2-ax =0$.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to a}(a^2-ax)=a^2-a\cdot a =0$

Comment: Alright cheers thanks for the help

Comment: What made you think that $\lim_{x\to a} [a^2-ax] = a$?

Answer (score 1):

The expression :- $\lim_{x \to a}[f(x)\cdot g(x)]=\lim_{x \to a} f(x)\cdot \lim_{x \to a}g(x)$ holds only if $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ . Exist separately.

For a basic counter example. take the sequence $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=\sin(\frac{1}{x})$.

Then the limit as $x\to 0$ of the product is $\lim_{x\to 0}x\sin(\frac{1}{x})=0$

But the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x) $ does not exist.

Otherwise consider an even basic example:-

$f(x)=\{\begin{align}
1\,,\text{x is rational}\\
0, \text{x is irrational}\\
\end{align}$

And take

$g(x)=\{\begin{align}
0\,,\text{x is rational}\\
1, \text{x is irrational}\\
\end{align}$

Then the limit of f and g do not exist for any point in $\mathbb{R}$ but the product function $f(x)g(x)$ is just the $0$ function ,i.e it takes the value $0$ $\forall\,x\in\mathbb{R}$ .

So the limit of the product function should just be $0$.

If you want counter-examples from sequences then take $a_{n}=(-1)^{n}$ and $b_{n}=(-1)^{n+1}$